# Is there an IP address widget for Android?

Tags: android, network-monitor

I am looking for an widget app that would print the IP address of wifi/mobile data on the home screen of my android phone. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found this:

IP Widget
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.dieterthiess.ipwidget&hl=en

It is quite useful and does what I need.